# How do you ensure jQuery is available when loaded asynchronously

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

Google allows you to load jQuery asynchronously like so:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=..." type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script> 
  //<![CDATA[
    google.load('jquery', '1.6');
  //]]>
</script>
<script src="scripta.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scriptb.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In later scripts, how do I ensure jQuery has been loaded? I could use `setInterval` to check whether `jQuery` is set, but suppose `scriptb.js` depends on `scripta.js`, and both are wrapped in a `setInterval` to wait for jQuery, and so the interval will "randomly" execute either one first.

How can I approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you are using this method rather than just including jquery 1.6 from the cdn?

Comment: I'm with Abe here, it's cheaper, faster, and simpler (with fewer HTTP requests/checks) with a simple `<script>` block for the include, e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Faster? I thought it was faster this way since the browser doesn't have to wait for the script to be fully loaded.

Comment: in this version it has to load `http://www.google.com/jsapi` *then* jQuery, then other scripts when they finish...more http requests, slower :)  In general, a loader for a single file is going to be slower almost 100% of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the optional setting `callback` ([documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/#Dynamic)):

```
google.load('jquery', '1.6', {"callback":jqueryLoaded});

function jqueryLoaded(){
alert('loaded');
}
```

Comment: But the callback would need to call a function on all scripts that need to know jQuery has been loaded, so that's not feasible.

Comment: That's the only callback you will get with using the google script loader. If it doesn't work for you, you would probably be better off not using the google loader to load the jquery.

Comment: @Ivan: You should load the extra scripts from the callback if it is impractical for those scripts to wait for a callback from this one. You could also consider using pub/sub (see eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe )

Comment: I guess I'll have to settle with loading the jQuery script directly. Thanks all for your input. I'll accept this answer since technically it's correct :)