# Loading jQuery asyncronously

Tags: jquery

My google analytics is supposed to load asynchronously. I am not sure really what this means:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxx']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
```

I don't need jQuery to be available immediately. Is there a way I can also make this asynchronous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics is loading asynchronously in your example. The part that handles that is `ga.async = true;`. Asynchronous means that the browser will continue to load rest of the content even if this one takes longer to load. In older browser, the content would be loaded in the order of the document and if something was slow to load, it would take longer for the browser to display the page.

If you want jQuery to load asynchronously, simply add `async="async"` to your `<script>` tag. Please keep in mind that only newer browser support this.

Alternatively, Google does offer [Google Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/) which allows you to load jQuery and many other libraries asynchronously. You can have a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244886/how-do-you-ensure-jquery-is-available-when-loaded-asynchronously) for an example.

Comment: do you have any link which says what are all browsers support asyn true attribute.

Comment: @kobe, @Matt Ball - That's not quite true anymore. Many browsers now support the async attribute including Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Firefox 3.6 was the first but many have implemented that feature now. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison%5Fof%5Flayout%5Fengines%5F%28HTML5%29#Attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison%5Fof%5Flayout%5Fengines%5F%28HTML5%29#Attributes) has a list. WebKit is used by Chrome and Safari and Gecko is Firefox.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9 supposedly also has support for the attribute.

Comment: It appears that while Chrome does support `async`, Safari does not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834077/which-browsers-support-script-async-async/6207768#6207768. A bugfix in WebKit does not immediately mean a bugfix in the browsers that use WebKit, since (especially Safari) the latest version of the browser does not necessarily mean the latest version of WebKit.

Answer (score 1):

[HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) provides a nice API for this sort of thing.

> #### JavaScript loader Load scripts in parallel but execute in order
>
> Head JS loads JavaScript files like
> images without blocking the page. Your
> page will be faster even with a single
> combined file.

```
head.js("/path/to/jquery.js", "/google/analytics.js", "/js/site.js",
function() {
    // all done
});
```

Comment: I don't want to sound negative but if this is so good then why are other people not using it ?

Comment: @UCC most pages that use jQuery require jQuery to be available right away.

Comment: the project has over 1700 follows on github.  what makes you say people aren't using it?

Comment: @all , i think only firefox support this asyn=true attribute right , thats what i read while implmenting google analytics

Comment: Both Gecko (Firefox) and WebKit (Chrome & Safari) now support the `async` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

On `Onload ()` event of a page you can insert a function that will automatically assign references to the JavaScript files you want to load in asynchronous manner after page loading.

```
function afterLoad(){
  var element1 = document.createElement(“script”);
  element1.src = “somefile.js”;
  element1.type=”text/javascript”;
  element1.async=true;
  document.getElementsByTagName(“head”)[0].appendChild(element1);
}
```

For more info check out http://www.tutkiun.com/2010/07/load-javascript-after-pageload.html

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to load JavaScript files asynchronously:

```
function loadJS(url) {
    var js = document.createElement('script');
    js.src = url;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(js);
}
```

Then just call it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    loadJS("http://pathToJSFile");
</script>
```