# Is this the best way to load google-analytics and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't need jQuery to be available immediately on page load:

So far I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '...']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function () {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            var gb = document.createElement('script'); gb.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            gb.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(gb, s); 
        })();
</script>
```

I am not 100% sure it is the most efficient way. Would anyone please let me know if I am doing things the best way.

Thanks

Comment: Most efficient in terms of what? Best way in what? Performance? Usability? You'll at least make sites dependant on jQuery to appear incorrectly until it has finished loading.

Comment: "Best way" is too subjective. What, specifically, do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello. Sorry if my question was not so clear. I did mention that I don't need jQuery to be available on page load. What I am looking for is a page that appears as quick as possible. jQuery when used will be needed usually more than 10 seconds after page load.

Comment: You're fine loading jQuery through a normal <script> tag in that case. Just make sure your <script> tag is at the end of the <body> section so that it doesn't block anything else from loading. If you're using Google's (or another) CDN, the method for including a fallback local copy I put in my answer below is a good safeguard in case the Googles are broken (or you're working while sitting in an airplane :P).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading jQuery asyncronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404292/loading-jquery-asyncronously)

Answer (score 4):

Mathias Bynens has written a post on optimizing the Google Analytics snippet. It's the "everything you wanted to know but were afraid to ask" version.

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet

**TL;DR version** he ends up with this:

```
<script>
  var _gaq = [['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X'], ['_trackPageview']];
  (function(d, t) {
    var g = d.createElement(t),
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
    g.async = g.src = '//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
  }(document, 'script'));
</script>
```

Minified, you end up with this:

```
<script>var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=g.src='//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'))</script>
```

> The optimized code minifies to 247 bytes and [executes faster](http://jsperf.com/async-analytics-snippet) than the original (440 bytes).

As for jQuery, rather than including it in the Google Analytics snippet, I'm personally a fan of the HTML5 Boilerplate method of linking to Google's CDN and then including a local fallback just in case it's not available.

```
  <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="js/libs/jquery.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Comment: +1 for finding this; but I would personally be wary of micro-optimisations like this and I'd urge people to read the entire blog post by Mathias before doing so.

Comment: It's a nice script, but it also removes some of the functionality such as checking the protocol and using appropriate version of GA.

Comment: Fair points. The original question was too open-ended to know exactly what the asker was trying to accomplish by "best way." This is possibly the "best" way if what he's trying to do is limit file sizes as much as possible.

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to minimize the time it takes to load.

Comment: According to the jsperf link I included, the optimized version runs up to twice as fast as the original, though with the caveats mentioned by other commenters above.

Answer (score 0):

*'Best'* is subjective, but of interest on this topic is an [article found here](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/).

The guy does some tests to load jQuery using [`google.load`](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/#GoogleLoad) and in the general way of `<script>` imports.

I personally always find the regular way to suffice, in terms of maintenance and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Problems is see with your code

1.If Google's CDN fails you have no fallback for local file.

2.GA scripts usually best at the bottom of the page, while loading jQuery is better at the head since all pages that derive from this page will be forced to place their jQuery related scripts below relative direction of jQuery on master page to work.